# How to build and install Eclipse Mylyn Connector plugin from source

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

An Eclipse Mylyn connector plugin, including a patch not available at the published update site, is available at https://github.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab.

I have been round and around in circles trying to work out how to get this installed and running in my Eclipse installation, without success.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

As suggested, I can install from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/gh-pages/. I can also build using maven and install from the resulting target update-site zip.

However, in both cases, the plugin behaves as if it were using the unpatched version. Specifically, when adding a new task repo, it performs validation which goes on for a long time (an hour) and fails with an error about a 50,000 API call limit. Wireshark shows lots of traffic to gitlab.com, with one burst of traffic every 5 seconds.

If I use Eclipse PDE to test the plugins in a debug Eclipce instance then everything works as expected!

I realise that this has wandered off the original topic.

Comment: Does it work with the update site [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/gh-pages/`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/gh-pages/)?

Comment: There is a `pom.xml` in that link which looks like it will build everything (using maven)

Comment: Yes https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/gh-pages/ did let me install it but it behaved, I think, as if it was the unpatched version.

Comment: I have used maven to build it from the pom. And I can install the result. However, I am still having trouble. I'll update the question.

Comment: Before you build it yourself, you have to increase the versions [here](https://github.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/blob/master/de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.ui/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L5), [here](https://github.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/blob/master/de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.core/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L5), [here](https://github.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/blob/master/de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab/feature.xml#L5) and [here](https://github.com/teknodan/mylyn-gitlab/blob/master/de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.updatesite/category.xml#L3). Use the version `2.2.0.qualifier` to avoid this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @greg-449 and @howlger, what I needed to do was build it myself using maven (`mvn package`) and then install using the site archive in `de.weingardt.mylyn.gitlab.updatesite/target`.

I'm not quite sure why I had to bump the version numbers (to `2.2.0.qualifier`). I also had to configure the main `pom.xml` version as `2.2.0-SNAPSHOT` and the `<parent>` version for the child POMs. Perhaps I could have got away with less if I had done a `mvn clean` first.

But all in all, it is now working. Thanks to all.

Comment: The version bump is only needed when you tried it before, because otherwise the cached plugins and features are used instead of the new ones with the same version.  The versions in the `pom.xml` files are irrelevant.